# Scala Play 2.3.0 with Anorm - Can't use Pattern Matching (IntelliJ cannot resolve symbol Row)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, anorm, playframework-2.3

I am developing an application with Scala (2.11) and Play Framework (2.3.0) on IntelliJ IDEA. I'm using Anorm to retrieve data from my database (MySQL with MariaDB).

Here is my first test application (it works):

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.db._
import anorm._

case class Client(id: Int, nom: String, prenom: String)

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    var result: List[(Int, String)] = List()
    val sqlQuery = SQL(
      """
        select idClient, nameClient from Clients
        where idClient = {idClient};
      """
    ).on("idClient" -> 1)

    DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
      result = sqlQuery().map(row =>
        row[Int]("IDClient") -> row[String]("NameClient")
      ).toList

    }
    Ok(result.toString)
  }
}
```

This works fine. I get the name of my client correctly. However, when I try to use pattern matching, like this:

```
result = sqlQuery().collect {
  case Row(idClient: Int, nameClient: String) => idClient -> nameClient
}
```

IntelliJ gives me an error, stating that it "`Cannot resolve Symbol Row`". As far as I know, Row is defined in the Anorm library, and so is SQL. It doesn't make sense that SQL would be found and not Row...

What's happening?

Comment: Does it compile with sbt?

Comment: Can't say why it can't resolve `Row`, as it as part of the `anorm` package (and my pure hatred of IDEs). But you ought to try the parser API (last piece of the docs) rather than pattern matching anyway: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAnorm

Comment: Christian > Yes, I assume it does, since I built the project with Typesafe Activator which includes sbt, and `anorm.SQL` works fine.

LimbSoup > Thanks. I did a basic test with the parser API, and it appears to be working correctly.
However, as it's not the first time I run into issues with external libraries and imports (I actually stopped trying to use Scala Slick for similar reasons before switching to Anorm), it would be awesome if I could find an answer as to why Row isn't resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anorm.Row extractor is not there in Play 2.3 . As suggested you could use parser.

Comment: Oh, well this explains that. Thanks, I already started using the parser API and it works well.