# Anorm pattern matching collect

Tags: scala, anorm

I don't understand why this code doesn't work for me:

```
import anorm._

DB.withConnection { implicit c => 

SQL("SELECT * FROM myTable")().collect {

case Row(name: String, type: Int) => {

//work with name and type

}}}
```

Compiler says that "Row is uknown" and intellij idea doesn't understand Row class also.

I remember that i've used collect method on lazy stream before but now i can't get what's going wrong

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262062/scala-play-2-3-0-with-anorm-cant-use-pattern-matching-intellij-cannot-resolv

Comment: as suggested there, you may use Parser API or update your Play if it's returned back (Row object and its unapply were removed in Play 2.3)

Comment: thanks, i don't understand then why they didn't mention this bug in documentation.. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.6/ScalaAnorm

Comment: no one cares, I suppose)

Comment: The bug and it fixes is indicated in the tracker on github. The documentation doesn't mention each and every bug fixes, especially when a regression like this one only affect one minor version.